# Weakest condition on module such that free prime localizations imply projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

I know that for a finitely presented commutative module $M$, if all prime localizations $M_\mathfrak{p}$ are free, then $M$ is projective. Is there a weakening or a converse of this statement? What can be said about a module if knowing its prime localizations are free implies projectivity?

Comment: It seems strange to ask about "p implies q" as a condition on an object (rather than as a theorem one wants to prove under some hypotheses). This is, of course, logically equivalent to asking "either not p or q." So you're asking about modules which are *either* projective *or* are such that at least one of their prime localizations isn't free, which doesn't seem like a particularly natural question.

Comment: And presumably "commutative module" means "module over a commutative ring"?

Comment: If the module has finite presentation, locally free implies flat (globally) and flat+finitely presented implies projective.